# Updating an array within foreach method Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi folks running into an error I think is related to scope that I was hoping I could get some advice on. I have an array that I am looping through that I want to push the results to. **When I try and push the results to public myArray:Array from within this.test.forEach I get the following error does not exist on type void.** Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
 export class componentName implements OnInit {
 public myArray:Array<any>;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.test = diff(this.example1, this.example2);

  this.test.forEach(function(part){
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(part.value));

    this.myArray.push(span); // error does not exist on type void
  });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first error is that you are using the wrong scope for `this`.

```
this.test.forEach(function(part){
```

Should be

```
 this.test.forEach((part)=>{
```

---

and you need to initialize your array.

```
public myArray:Array<any> = [];
```